# Why is this sqlcmd batch file not outputting the file?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a batch file with this code.

```
sqlcmd -S Database -E -Q "select * from People" -o "C:\test.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

The batch file runs, and seems to pull the results of the query, but the output file never appears. Is there something wrong with the code, or is there a better way to output a sql query to a  .csv file?

Comment: Also when I run the query through the export wizard in sql server it returns an error saying that this SQL statement is not a query even though it does return results when run inside sql server.

Comment: The problem is with the SQL command. I tried a different one and it exported correctly.

Comment: Try leaving the quotes off of the column separator (-s, instead of -s",")

Answer (score 0):

Nick, I know this is old, but maybe could help newcomers as me. If you're working with a batch file, make sure you doesn't have a return char after the sql statement. Mine wasn't generating a file either, and then I found out that I pressed ENTER / RETURN after my statement.